# Change sorting order regardless of sectionNameKeyPath in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to group by section in which the `sectionNameKeyPath` is according to Category.

My categories are: Adult, Child, Vision, None.

Ascending order sort: Adult, Child, None, Vision

Descending order sort: Vision, None, Child, Adult

I want None category to come at last always regardless of sort order.

Ascending desired sort: Adult, Child, Vision, None

Descending desired sort: Vision, Child, Adult, None

Code used is as follows:

```
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedOC, sectionNameKeyPath: "category", cacheName: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are storing category as String and String value can only sort in the Alphabetically order.
Is it possible if you can create a numeric field in the database? And store numeric value like
Adult = 1, Child = 2, Vision = 3, None = 4,
Through you can easily arrange and sort data either in ascending or descending order. Hope this help you.

Comment: But in case of descending order also the NONE should be the last item.

Comment: You could do like first fetch "Adult = 1, Child = 2, Vision = 3" data in sorting order and store in list#1. And next fetch only item for "None" and store in list#2, finally merge both lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to amend the CoreData model, you could create a new entity to represent the categories.  The `Category` entity would have three attributes: `name` (string), `ascOrder` (Integer 16) and `descOrder` (Integer 16).  Then (as a one-off task) create four `Category` objects with values as follows:

```
name        ascOrder    descOrder
====        ========    =========
Adult       1           3
Child       2           2
Vision      3           1
None        4           4
```

Replace the `category` attribute of your entity with a (to-one) relationship to `Category`.  The inverse relationship should be to-many.  Now rather than setting the attribute value to, for example, "Adult", you would set the relationship to the `Category` object with `name` "Adult".  You can then configure your FRC to sort the objects by key `category.ascOrder` or `category.descOrder` and specify the corresponding `sectionNameKeyPath`.

The result will be that your table will be grouped into sections and sorted correctly.  However, because the `sectionNameKeyPath` is `ascOrder` (or `descOrder`), the section `name` property will be 1,2,3 or 4, rather than "Adult", "Child", etc.  To fix this, in your tableView's `titleForHeaderInSection` or `viewForHeaderInSection` method, don't use:

```
let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
let sectionName = sectionInfo.name
```

but instead get the name by traversing the relationship from the first item in the section:

```
let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
let firstItem = sectionInfo.objects![0] as! YourEntity
let sectionName = firstItem.name
```

There might be similar issues with index titles, if you are using indexes.

If your app is already live, one downside to this approach will be the need to undertake a migration of your data.  I can't remember whether lightweight migration can handle replacing an attribute with a relationship to a new entity; I leave it to you to investigate.